# Free event tracking for iOS with raw data export

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-analytics, analytics

I'm looking for a free analytics tool to track events on iOS.
However, I'm not interested in graphs or aggregate data. I simply need a raw log of the events like this:

> - 1/01/2012 10:58pm: User#3001 clicked "Play" on video #1828
> - 1/01/2012 11:08pm: User#2829 clicked "Play" on video #1837
> - 1/01/2012 11:27pm: User#2829 clicked "Stop" on video #1827
> - 1/01/2012 11:37pm: User#3001 clicked "Pause" on video #1827
> - .....

I've looked at [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html), but they seem to only support aggregate data.
Similarly, the documentation on [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/) doesn't mention a raw data export.
And the free plan on [Localytics](http://www.localytics.com/plans/) does not support event tracking.

Does any mobile analytics service offer a free plan with access to raw event data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flurry does include the ability to log events. Take a look at `+ (void)logEvent:(NSString *)eventName withParameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters;`. The `NSDictionary` can include the type of information you've indicated.